# How to scrape text using RSelenium in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rselenium

I would like to scrape the text "VIRGINIA TECH" from the site http://stats.statbroadcast.com/statmonitr/?id=102197 using the package RSelenium.

the css selector for the particular text I would like to scrape is:

`.valigntop:nth-child(1) .width6-3-4.marginr`

After opening the remote driver and navigating to the site I try:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", '.valigntop:nth-child(1) .width6-3-4.marginr')
doc <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
current_doc <- read_html(doc)
current_doc <- html_text(current_doc)
```

This returns a big block of text and not the text I want "VIRGINIA TECH".

After scrape what I would like:

```
current_doc
[1] "VIRGINIA TECH"
```

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Comment: the following XPath seems to work pretty well `(//div[contains(@class, "teamname")])[1]`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I try `remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "(//div[contains(@class, "teamname")])[1]")`  it returns an `unexpected symbol` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading thru this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html) 
I found that this works great to scrape my desired text.

```
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', ".valigntop:nth-child(1) .width6-3-4.marginr")
current_doc <- unlist(lapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()}))
```

Result:

```
current_doc
[1] "VIRGINIA TECH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one.

```
`webElems <- unlist(remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', ".valigntop:nth-child(1) .width6-3-4.marginr")$getElementText())`
```

This works too!!